# How to share excel workbook with python?

Tags: excel, python-3.x, shared

I'm unable to preserve shared properties after editing with openpyxl; so I need a way to share the excel using python.  Please can you advise how?

Comment: Could you provide more details? Are you trying to share the file with other folks in your team? over email? in a shared drive? what properties are not getting preserved?

Comment: You may want to try checking out - https://stackoverflow.com/q/57363072/2279816

Comment: The file is in a shared drive. It is shared among ten users. When openpyxl saves the file, the shared document becomes unshared. I want it to be shared. I tried the above solution, it just overwrites new excel with the old one.

Comment: Could you share the code you're using?