# How to keep the share properties of an excel with python openpyxl?

Tags: python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

I have trouble trying to keep the sharing properties of an excel. I tried this :[Python and openpyxl is saving my shared workbook as unshared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57363072/python-and-openpyxl-is-saving-my-shared-workbook-as-unshared) but the part of vout just cancels all the modification I made with the script

To explain the problem :

- There's an excel file that is shared in which people can do some modification
- Python reads and writes on it
- When I save the workbook in the excel file, it automatically either drops the sharing property or when I try to keep it, it just doesn't do any modification

Can someone help me please ?

Comment: How do you save an excel workbook in a shared form?  To mu knowledge, the ability to share a workbook or not share it is a function of the server on which the workbook is stored (i.e Google Drive, Dropbox, OneDrive, etc) thus it is not a function of openpyxl but the service used to store the workbook.

Comment: you might want to put the relevant part of the python code here - some folks skip over the question if you need to navigate off SO to get the entirety of the question

Answer (score 1):

I'll get a little more precise, as requested.

The sharing mode is the one Microsoft provides. You can see the button below:

[Share button Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5K6o7.png)

The excel is stored on a server. Several users can write on it at the same time but when I launch my script, it stops automatically the sharing property, so everyone that is writing on it just can't do modification anymore and every modif they did is lost.

First I treated my Excel normally :

```
DLT=openpyxl.load_workbook(myPath)
ws=DLT['DLT']
...my modifications on ws...
DLT.save()
DLT.close()
```

But then I tried this ([Python and openpyxl is saving my shared workbook as unshared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57363072/python-and-openpyxl-is-saving-my-shared-workbook-as-unshared))

```
DLT=openpyxl.load_workbook(myPath)
ws=DLT['DLT']
zin = zipfile.ZipFile(myPath, 'r')
buffers = []
   for item in zin.infolist():
       buffers.append((item, zin.read(item.filename)))
zin.close()
...my modif on ws...
DLT.save()
zout = zipfile.ZipFile(myPath, 'w')
    for item, buffer in buffers:
        zout.writestr(item, buffer)
zout.close()
DLT.close()
```

The second one just doesn't save my modification on `ws`.

The thing I would like to do, is not to get rid of the sharing property. I would need to keep it while I write on it. Not sure if it is possible. I have one alternative solution that is to use another file, and just copy/paste by hand the new data from this file to the DLT one.

Answer (score 0):

well... after playing with it back and forth, for some weird reason zipfile.infolist() does contains the sheet data as well, so here's my way to fine tune it, using the shared_pyxl_save example the previous gentleman provided

basically instead of letting the old file overriding the sheet's data, use the old one

```
def shared_pyxl_save(file_path, workbook):
    """
    `file_path`: path to the shared file you want to save
    `workbook`: the object returned by openpyxl.load_workbook()
    """
    zin = zipfile.ZipFile(file_path, 'r')
    buffers = []
    for item in zin.infolist():
        if "sheet1.xml" not in item.filename:
            buffers.append((item, zin.read(item.filename)))
    zin.close()

    workbook.save(file_path)
    """ loop through again to find the sheet1.xmls and put it into buffer, else will show up error"""
    zin2 = zipfile.ZipFile(file_path, 'r')
    for item in zin2.infolist():
        if "sheet1.xml" in item.filename:
            buffers.append((item, zin2.read(item.filename)))
    zin2.close()
    
    #finally saves the file
    zout = zipfile.ZipFile(file_path, 'w')
    for item, buffer in buffers:
        zout.writestr(item, buffer)
    zout.close()
    workbook.close()
```