# python openpyxl: maintain shared property

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am working with openpyxl with a shared excel file. i want to add some data to the file and then save it. The problem is that the save method removes the shared property of the file

```
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(path, keep_vba=False)
worksheet = workbook[sheet]
worksheet.cell(row=1, column=2, value="Test")
workbook.save(path)
```

I tried the solution offered here:

[Python and openpyxl is saving my shared workbook as unshared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57363072/python-and-openpyxl-is-saving-my-shared-workbook-as-unshared)

But this solution **removes ** all data changes even it maintains the shared property

Any idea?

Comment: Can you be more specific? load_workbook does't have an append mode